# Maximum probability of sum occurring in a dice(s) roll in such a way

Tags: probability, permutations, binomial-coefficients

One fair die is rolled: let 'x' denote the number that comes up. We then roll 'x' dice(s), and let the sum of the resulting numbers be 'y'. Finally, roll 'y' dice(s) and let 'z' be the sum of the resulting 'y' numbers. Let the expected value of 'z' be 'a', we have to find 'a'.

===================================================================
My approach:-

for 'x' all numbers have same probability of occurring  after that if we consider cases for 'y':

1 dice roll

2 dice(s) roll.. 
.

.

6 dice(s) roll

and sum up the possibilities we get something like this

sum     expected probability(out of $6^7$)

1       7776

2       9072

3       10584

4       12348

5       14406

6       16807

7       11832

8       12507

9       13076

10      13482

11      13650

12      13482

13      12852

14      12897

15      12772

16      12453

17      11928

18      11207

19      10332

20      9387

21      8292

22      7101

23      5880

24      4697

25      3612

26      2667

27      1876

28      1251

29      786

30      462

31      252

32      126

33      56

34      21

35      6

36      1

6 is having maximum probability i.e. 16807
and then 'y'=6.

and we know that if we roll 6 dice(s) then the probability of sum that is maximum is 21

so 'z' should be 21 but this is not the answer can someone suggest any different approach

Answer (score 0):

Call $x^*$ the outcome of the first dice. Then we throw $x^*$ independent dies whose outcome is $x_i$ and we call $y^*=\sum_{i=1}^{x^*}x_i$. Finally, we throw $y^*$ independent dices whose outcome is $y_i$ and we call $z=\sum_{i=1}^{y^*}y_i$. We are looking for $\mathbb{E}(z)$. So, we can do this using the Law of Iterated Expectations (LIE), as follows:
$$\mathbb{E}(z)=\mathbb{E}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{y^*}y_i\bigg)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(y_1+\dots+y_{y^*}\mid y^*))=\mathbb{E}(y^*\mathbb{E}(y_i))=\frac{21}{6}\mathbb{E}(y^*)$$
Where the second to last equality follows from the fact that each throw is independent and identically distributed, so $y^*$ determines the number of throws but not the outcome of each of them. To finish the problem then we can proceed again using the LIE as follows:
$$\mathbb{E}(z)=\frac{21}{6}\mathbb{E}(y^*)=\frac{21}{6}\mathbb{E}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{x^*}x_i\bigg)=\frac{21}{6}\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(x_1+\dots+x_{x^*}\mid x^*))=\frac{21}{6}\mathbb{E}(x^*\mathbb{E}(x_i))=\bigg(\frac{21}{6}\bigg)^3$$

Comment: I need answer for the expected value of 'a' i.e. the sum which has the maximum probability of occurring and it should be an integer i guess

Comment: I´m sorry, but that´s not what the description of the problem say. I think you should rephrase it then.

Comment: The expected value 'z' is sum of resulting 'y' so 'z' has to be an integer. Can you explain what $(21/6)^3$ is?

Comment: 21/6 is the expected value of a dice throw, which is $1/6(1+2+3+4+5+6)$, it doesn´t have to be integer. If you flip a fair coin where one face is 1 and the other is 0, the expectation is 0.5, which is not integer either. In this case, I defined the sums you´re looking for, and it turns out that the expected sum is $(21/6)^3=42.875$